# Javscript optimization with for loops and intervals

Tags: javascript, html, performance, optimization, canvas

im making a game in java script (a ray caster), and it is really slow as there are many nested for loops and intervals, with large arrays, is there any way to optimize it, and if there is, will it still be very slow when i start to do bigger math to calculate line-line intersection, i just dont think im doing this in the best way possible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas width="500px" height="500px" id="c"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
  c = document.getElementById("c");
  w = c.width;
  h = c.height;
  ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var tilesize = 50;
  var walls = [];


  var player = {
    x: 80,
    y: 80,
    size: 10,
    speed: 1,
    dir: 0,
    rot: 0,
    rotSpeed: 0.05,
    rotDir: 0,
  }


  var map = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ]
  ]





  function keydown(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 87:
        player.dir = 1;
        break;
      case 83:
        player.dir = -1;
        break;
      case 68:
        player.rotDir = -1;
        break;
      case 65:
        player.rotDir = 1;
        break;
    }

  }

  function keyup(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 87:
        player.dir = 0;
        break;
      case 83:
        player.dir = 0;
        break;
      case 68:
        player.rotDir = 0;
        break;
      case 65:
        player.rotDir = 0;
        break;
    }

  }

  var gameloop = setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    //move
    rotstep = player.rotSpeed * player.rotDir
    movestep = player.speed * player.dir;
    player.rot += rotstep;
    newY = player.y - Math.cos(player.rot) * movestep;
    newX = player.x - Math.sin(player.rot) * movestep;

    leftbY = (player.y - 10) - Math.cos(player.rot) * movestep;
    leftbX = (player.x - 10) - Math.sin(player.rot) * movestep;
    rightbY = (player.y + 10) - Math.cos(player.rot) * movestep;
    rightbX = (player.x + 10) - Math.sin(player.rot) * movestep;
    //borders 
    var leftcol = Math.floor((leftbX) / tilesize)
    var leftrow = Math.floor((leftbY) / tilesize)
    var rightcol = Math.floor((rightbX) / tilesize)
    var rightrow = Math.floor((rightbY) / tilesize)
    if (map[rightcol][rightrow] == 0 && map[leftcol][leftrow] == 0) {
      player.y = newY;
      player.x = newX;
    }

    //map
    for (y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
      for (x = 0; x < map[y].length; x++) {
        if (map[y][x] == 1) {
          var wallSeg = {
            coordX: x * tilesize,
            coordY: y * tilesize,
            sizeX: tilesize,
            sizeY: 0,
          }
          var wallSeg2 = {
            coordX: x * tilesize,
            coordY: y * tilesize,
            sizeX: 0,
            sizeY: tilesize,
          }
          var wallSeg3 = {
            coordX: x * tilesize,
            coordY: (y * tilesize) + tilesize,
            sizeX: tilesize,
            sizeY: 0,
          }
          var wallSeg4 = {
            coordX: (x * tilesize) + tilesize,
            coordY: y * tilesize,
            sizeX: 0,
            sizeY: tilesize,
          }
          walls.push(wallSeg)
          walls.push(wallSeg2)
          walls.push(wallSeg3)
          walls.push(wallSeg4)

        }
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {
      var currentwall = walls[i]
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.moveTo(currentwall.coordX, currentwall.coordY);
      ctx.lineTo((currentwall.coordX) + currentwall.sizeX, (currentwall.coordY) + currentwall.sizeY);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    //player
    markerY = player.y - Math.cos(player.rot) * 30;
    markerX = player.x - Math.sin(player.rot) * 30;
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.ellipse(player.x, player.y, player.size, player.size, player.rot * (Math.PI / 180), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    //marker
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(player.x, player.y)
    ctx.lineTo(markerX, markerY)
    ctx.strokeStyle = "Blue"
    ctx.stroke();

  }, 1000 / 30)

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    keydown(event);
  })
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    keyup(event);
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Probably a great use case to consider for [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Spawn process(es) to do calculations and report results while main process handles UI. Take a look at the first [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#further_examples)

Comment: Here is a related project: https://github.com/ercang/raytracer-js

Comment: Do you need to do all that `walls` stuff on each game loop, can't you just do it once at the start.  Also, it looks like you keep appending to the `walls` array each game loop without clearing it out, making it increasingly bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way, instead of rendering each individual line segment, just render a square for each one, i dont need to render the line segments, i just need the varibles, and also only initilizeing the walls at the begining.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <canvas width="500px" height="500px" id="c"></canvas>   
    </body>
    <script>
        
        c = document.getElementById("c");
        w = c.width;
        h = c.height;
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var tilesize = 50;
    var walls = [];
    rayangle = 35;


        var player = {
            x : 80,
            y: 80,
            size : 10,
            speed: 1,
            dir: 0,
      rot: 0,
      rotSpeed: 0.05,
      rotDir: 0,
        }


        var map = [
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,],
            [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,],
            [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,]
            ]
            

      for(y = 0;y < map.length;y++){
                    for(x = 0;x < map[y].length;x++){

                    ctx.fillStyle = ["white", "black"][map[y][x]];
                    ctx.fillRect(x * tilesize, y * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);

                    if(map[y][x] == 1){
                      var wallSeg = {
                        coordX : x * tilesize,
                        coordY : y * tilesize,
                        sizeX : tilesize,
                        sizeY : 0,
                      }
                      var wallSeg2 = {
                        coordX : x * tilesize,
                        coordY : y * tilesize,
                        sizeX : 0,
                        sizeY : tilesize,
                      }
                      var wallSeg3 = {
                        coordX : x * tilesize,
                        coordY : (y * tilesize)+tilesize,
                        sizeX : tilesize,
                        sizeY : 0,
                      }
                      var wallSeg4 = {
                        coordX : (x * tilesize) + tilesize,
                        coordY : y * tilesize,
                        sizeX : 0,
                        sizeY : tilesize,
                      }
                      walls.push(wallSeg)
                      walls.push(wallSeg2)
                      walls.push(wallSeg3)
                      walls.push(wallSeg4)

                    }
                    }    
                }
        

            

            function keydown(event){
                switch(event.keyCode){
                    case 87:
                        player.dir = 1;
                    break;
                    case 83:
                        player.dir = -1;
                    break;
          case 68:
                        player.rotDir = -1;
                    break;
                    case 65:
                        player.rotDir = 1;
                    break;
                }

            }
            function keyup(event){
                switch(event.keyCode){
                    case 87:
                        player.dir = 0;
                    break;
                    case 83:
                        player.dir = 0;
                    break;
          case 68:
                        player.rotDir = 0;
                    break;
                    case 65:
                        player.rotDir = 0;
                    break;
                }

            }
        
            var gameloop = setInterval(function(){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);

                //move
        rotstep = player.rotSpeed * player.rotDir
                movestep = player.speed * player.dir;
        player.rot += rotstep;
        newY = player.y - Math.cos(player.rot) * movestep;
        newX = player.x - Math.sin(player.rot) * movestep;

        leftbY = (player.y - 10) - Math.cos(player.rot) * movestep;
        leftbX = (player.x - 10) - Math.sin(player.rot) * movestep;
        rightbY = (player.y + 10) - Math.cos(player.rot) * movestep;
        rightbX = (player.x + 10) - Math.sin(player.rot) * movestep;
                //borders 
                 var leftcol = Math.floor((leftbX)/tilesize)
         var leftrow = Math.floor((leftbY)/tilesize)
         var rightcol = Math.floor((rightbX)/tilesize)
         var rightrow = Math.floor((rightbY)/tilesize)
         if(map[rightcol][rightrow] == 0 && map[leftcol][leftrow] == 0 ){
            player.y = newY;
            player.x = newX;
         }
         
                //map
                for(y = 0;y < map.length;y++){
                    for(x = 0;x < map[y].length;x++){

                    ctx.fillStyle = ["white", "black"][map[y][x]];
                    ctx.fillRect(x * tilesize, y * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);

                    }
                    }    
                
        

        //rays     
                //player
        markerY = player.y - Math.cos(player.rot) * 30;
        markerX = player.x - Math.sin(player.rot) * 30;
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
                ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.ellipse(player.x, player.y, player.size, player.size, player.rot * (Math.PI/180), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        //marker
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(player.x,player.y)
        ctx.lineTo(markerX,markerY)
        ctx.strokeStyle = "Blue"
        ctx.stroke();

            },1000/30)

            document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
                keydown(event);
            })
      document.addEventListener("keyup",function(event){
                keyup(event);
            })

    </script>
</html>
```